# Jquery show causing content not to show until scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a click function to hide all div's with a class and then show the one i want . But the problem is that when that div shows . Only its property changes to display:block , but it does not shows any content until i scroll the page up or down . After scrolling it appears suddenly . The code is

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.nav-next-arrow', function(){

    var total_sep=jQuery(".total_sep").val();
    var custom_clock=jQuery(".custom_clock").val(); 
    if(check_value_NAN_empty(custom_clock)==true)
    {
        var final_clock=0;
    }
    else
    {
        var final_clock=custom_clock;
    }
    var additon=parseInt(final_clock)+1;
    jQuery(".custom_clock").val(additon);   
    jQuery( ".mi-cst-pg" ).hide();  
    jQuery( ".mi-cst-pg" ).eq( additon ).show(500);
    return false; 
});
```

Normally the content shows instantly when i used show in any other projects i have done and there is no need to scroll up or down to show content .

Comment: Whats the html? Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Andre The html is a very complex part . Its first generated via a plugin and then i am using lots of jquery to shuffle it and move to new containers . It will be difficult to make a fiddle :(

Comment: As is, I don't think this question is answerable... Try to create a fiddle, isolating the parts. You can copy the final html via browser console, even if it's generated dynamically. Maybe you even find out the problem in the process.